# what does character '!' mean in array assignment in C

Tags: c, arrays, special-characters

I have this code excerpt and don't understand some syntax in it.

- What does `string[index] = '!'` mean?
- What does `string[index] == '~'` mean?

And `(string[index]++)` probably means (the value of `string[index] + 1`)? The problem is that, in a larger context, that value should be a character. So, will it be treated as an ASCII code?

```
// Function to increment character and carry over if necessary

void incrementChar(char string[], int index)
{
    if (string[index] == '\0')
    {
        string[index] = '!';
    }
    else if (string[index] == '~')
    {
        string[index] = '!';
        incrementChar(string, index + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        string[index]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `string[]` is an array of characters.  `string[index] = '!'` simply stores a `'!'` character into a certain cell of the array.  There's no special meaning of `!` here; it's no different in principle than saying `string[index] = 'A'` to store the letter `A`.

Comment: But, yes, this code is doing something tricky with the characters in the string, incrementing their values, presumably to do some kind of encoded arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you, Steve, that solves my problem.

Comment: I started a longer post explaining the code yesterday, but I seem to have lost it.  Suffice it to say that there might be a bug: I suspect that in the first case, `string[index] = '!'` should probably be `string[index] = '!'; string[index+1] = '\0'`.

Comment: You're right in this context. Since this code is part of a larger context, however, your concern doesn't exist in that context. But thank you anyway!